# How can I compile OpenCV 2.2 to use in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, opencv

I am trying to compile and use OpenCV 2.2 in my iPhone app, (specifically object-finding) but I can't figure out how to do it.  I have tried some tutorials but none have worked.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#examples

You'll probably get more answers here if you let us know what you tried, what happened, and that sort of thing. "Something didn't work" doesn't give us much to go on.